# My custom hook is warning: "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

New in React, trying to implement a custom hook that call a function when user keydown "Enter":

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'

const useEnterToCall = callBackFunction => {
  const listenToCallWithEnter = e => {
    e.code === 'Enter' && callBackFunction()
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', listenToCallWithEnter)
    return () => document.removeEventListener('keydown', listenToCallWithEnter)
  }, [])
}

export default useEnterToCall
```

And in my component i import this custom hook and try to use:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import useEnterToCall from '../../hooks/useEnterToCall.hook'

const Login = () => {
    
    useEffect(() => {
      if (valid) {
        useEnterToCall(submit())
      }
    }, [])
}
```

I'm facing this error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component.

Don't understanding why i'm getting this error.

Comment: Either you've skipped a fair amount of code, or your `useEffect`  (second one) is not inside of the body of a function component (i.e. what the error says).

Comment: i supress the code, if i use only useEffect(), my component works normally, but when i put the useEffect with my custom hook, i receive this error.

Comment: You need to show a minimal *but complete* example, which this is not. The "import this custom hook" is not going to work and would give you the same error message (and you don't specify). In other words, we don't know how much is what you've actually done vs. decided was unimportant even it it looks like a problem in and of itself.

Comment: thanks @crashmstr, i try to put some more code in the question

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting this error because it is not allowed to call a hook inside useEffect. To be specific, a hook should be called at the top level, and should not be called conditionally.

For more information, see here - [Rules of hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level)

Answer (score 1):

yeah you cannot call custom hook  inside the useEffect

```
    import useEnterToCall from '../../hooks/useEnterToCall.hook'
    function yourFn() {
       console.log("log enter");
     }

   useEnterToCall(yourFn);
```

this will work !